# "Meteorology" vs "Climatology" and meteor

Tags: ambiguity

I am having a naive uneasiness regarding these 3 words.

The text ( TOEFL ( Test Of English For Foreign Language )) by native speakers
says,

> Meteorology is the scientific study of **weather condition**.

According to the Merriam Unabridged Online, the brief etymology of the word
Meteorology is below.

> French or Greek; French météorologie, from Middle French, from Greek meteōrologia, from meteōro- astronomical phenomenon, **thing in the heaven above (from meteōron)** + -logia -logy — more at meteor

So I checked with the etymology of the word meteor, and found accordingly.

> Middle English, from Middle French meteore, from Medieval Latin meteorum, from Greek meteōron astronomical phenomenon, **thing in the heaven above,** from neuter of meteōros high in air, raised off the ground, from meta- + -eōros (akin to Greek aeirein to lift, raise, aiora suspension)

So what is common for both of the words, Meteorology, meteor, etymologically speaking, is "thing in the heaven above".

And the definition of Climatology.

> the science that deals with climates and investigates their phenomena and causes

I have to go to the word climate for its etymology.

From the climate,

> Middle English climat, from Middle French climat, from Late Latin climat-, clima, from Greek klimat-, klima inclination, the supposed slope of the earth toward the pole, region, clime, from klinein to slope, incline — more at lean

Now, my question is should I use the word Meteorology as historically it is old to denote the science of weather condition, or the new word which etymologically 
speaking has nothing to do with either meteorology or meteor, to denote the science of the weather condition? Which is better?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see what etymology has to do with this. *Weather* is not the same thing as *climate*, therefore *meteorology* and *climatology* are two separate branches of science. Which one you should choose depends on what exactly  you're talking about.

Comment: hm...From the Merriam, climate **the average course or condition of the weather at a particular place over a period of many years as exhibited in absolute extremes, means, and frequencies of given departures from these means, of temperature, wind velocity, precipitation, and other weather elements**. So the scope of the word climatology is more limited than meteorology?

Comment: *Weather* is the state of the atmosphere at a given time and place. *Climate* is the statistics of weather over long periods of time. So the scope of climatology is **different** from that of meteorology. More at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climatology#Differences_with_meteorology

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank you for your providing me with an interesting source. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Never turn to etymology to settle questions of meaning or usage. That’s a fallacy. In fact, it’s specifically called the Etymological Fallacy. Use *weather* to mean what the dictionary says it means, and where other people use it, and use *climate* to mean what the dictionary means, and where other people use it. Ignore etymology except to satisfy your own curiosity of the *history* of the word. It should not and can not be relied on for usage or definition purposes. If you’re confused about *weather* vs *climate*, first study their defs in an English dict, then look them up in a transl. dict.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is premised on the [Etymological Fallacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy), and confuses the definitions of *weather* and *climate*.

Comment: "regarding these 3 words."? Which 3 words? I see only 2 mentioned, climatology and meteorology. "what is common for both of the words": which two words? And you want to know what is _common_ between the two (once specified)? This is all very unclear. Weather (or meteorology) is if is it rained today, the climate (or climatology) is if this area is a rain forest or desert. A meteor is entirely unrelated.

Comment: @DanBron Okay, **Interweaving** etymologies of both words ( and that of meteor ) was not my intention to distract or distort or even trying to set up a "righteous reason", I was firstly perplexed between the relationship between the meteor and meteorology, that's why I made a statement about their etymologies.Climatology came secondly, which further confused me if you believe or not. But if you are not satisfied with my comment, then please do as you so.

Comment: @DanBron And didn't you realize your "own fallacy"? When we talked about the difficulties of TOFL iBT at ELL, link[https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/what-do-you-think-why-the-english-test-for-non-native-speakers-toefl-ibt-has-be]. I told you to wait for a moment until I reply since the husband of my father's daughter died ( it was a real event ). You told me as if you are a best friend of mine or something, as "**My deepest condolences. My thoughts are with you and your family**". To be honest I was a bit upset then, since you are not a family member of our family

Comment: and that statement is far stretched. Weren't you able to say simply, "oh I'm sorry for that." or just "My condolences". Deepest condolences?  Screw it. And your thoughts were with me and my family? Screw it. **That's the fallacy**. We only met through internet and it was the first time I received such a solemn condolence from a person who I only met once on the internet.

Comment: Since per your saying you are a science nerd, can't you even handle simple manner  when you saw a death of **a family member of a person who you only once met --through internet --**? Aren't you lacking social modesty? Fallacy? Ha, You were a fallacy.

Comment: @KentaroTomono I am hearing you are upset. It was not my intention to upset you. I was sincere in my condolences, that is a tragic event, and I have had similar tragic events in my family, and I have felt the feelings. I did not press you for a response to those earlier comments, and I still won’t. As for this question: we have a duty on SE to manage the “library”, and take each question on its merits. It is independent of our individual feelings. This question is based on a false premise; I thought it my duty to inform you of this (as it’s the answer to your Q), and others who read it.

Comment: @DanBron I'm talking about **how much we are close between you and me**. I think as you said, you seem to be a science nerd, but it seems to me you are lacking a bit of social skills. I said only "I am going to reply to you formally", but you went too deep, which in turn it sounds like you don't care at all. **Social fallacy** would be such a kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start with Etymology => "history" of the word. Which does not mean current meaning, rather the history of the word.

Meteorology = is about "weather conditions", while Climatology is about "climate". Weather is a bit of climate, which is a general, statistical entity. Simply put (not accurate though) - weather: "it is raining now", while climate: "it is generally dry in this time of the season".

As for the etymology of meteor and meteorology: meteor = 'smth high in the sky', meteorology - 'study of smth high in the sky'. 'logy' is science. Weather is all from sky (according to Greeks and others who believed in gods), thus the science is studying that. Though it does not study meteors. They are studied by astronomers (astronomy - law of the stars), as they meteors are from space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Kindly let me have time a bit. Sorry.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. My mistake was my composition was not good. I am sorry for that.